# Is anyone using access.conf and netgroup authentication with sssd?

Tags: ldap, pam, sssd

I want to be able to authenticate users (via ssh) to specific groups of hosts based on the users' LDAP netgroup membership. The LDAP server is dsee7. The distro is OEL 6.5 with openldap as the client.

The only account we don't want to authenticate using LDAP is root.

sssd.conf looks like this:

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss,pam,autofs

domains = default
[nss]
filter_groups = root
filter_users = root
reconnection_retries = 3
entry_cache_timeout = 300
entry_cache_nowait_percentage = 75

[pam]


[domain/default]
auth_provider = ldap
ldap_id_use_start_tls = True
chpass_provider = ldap
cache_credentials = True
ldap_search_base = dc=e-durp,dc=com
id_provider = ldap
ldap_uri = ldaps://lvl1.lvs01.edurp.com/ ldaps://lvl1.lvs01.edurp.com/
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/openldap/cacerts
```

The /etc/openldap/ldap.conf looks like this:

```
URI ldaps://ldap.edurp.com/ ldaps://ldap1.edurp.com ldaps://ldap2.edurp.com
BASE dc=edurp,dc=com
TLS_CACERTDIR /etc/openldap/cacerts
TLS_CACERT /etc/openldap/cacerts/ldap_ca.cert
TLS_REQCERT never
```

nsswitch.conf looks like this:

```
passwd:     files compat
shadow:     files compat
passwd_compat: sss
shadow_compat: sss
group:      files sss
hosts:      files dns
bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files sss
netgroup:   sss files
publickey:  nisplus
automount:  files ldap
aliases:    files nisplus
```

And /etc/pam.d/system-auth reads:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

So I tried adding a netgroup to /etc/security/access.conf like so:

```
#- : ALL : ALL
-:@eeederp: ALL
```

and restarted sssd just in case . . .

My user belongs to the netgroup eeederp and is still able to get in using his LDAP password.

Any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: I just realized I could add "debug" to any line in /etc/pam.d/system-auth. Perhaps I'll get some answers there.

Comment: `16:24:35 node00 sshd[55306]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.65.4.38  user=eeederp`
`16:24:36 node00 sshd[55306]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.65.4.38 user=eeederp`
`16:24:36 node00 sshd[55306]: pam_access(sshd:account): access denied for user `eeederp' from '10.65.4.38'`
`16:24:36 node00 sshd[55307]: fatal: Access denied for user eeederp by PAM account configuration`
`16:24:36 node00 sshd[55306]: Failed password for eeederp from 10.65.4.38 port 56330 ssh2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Red Hat 6 authenticating against AD using Netgroups successfully. I am trying to get it authenticating against an old Sun LDAP server and am not having luck. I can see the netgroups, I can see the user with "getent netgroup {name of netgroup} and I can su to the user. However when I attempt to login it does not work.

What I can tell you from my AD authentication is taht your netgroup statement is the opposite of what you want. When you begin with a - it means DO NOT allow them to login. Try switching that to a + meaning DO allow the users in this netgroup to login.

Also use the getent command to check to see if you can see your users and netgroup proprely.
getent passwd {username}
getent netgroup {name of netgroup}

Remember getent also looks at your local files (as defined in nsswitch.conf) for this information so be sure the information is only available via LDAP.

Hope this helps,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert on pam but if you're using access.conf you need a reference to pam_access.so. perhaps:
account   required    pam_access.so

Just keep a root shell open while you test. I've managed to lock out the root user with a bad pam edit.

Comment: Yes. pam_access.so needs to be in /etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac an systemauth-ac.
I would double check the syntax of your access.conf file. I have Red Hat 7 and it is a different format than what you have shown here. I have - : @eeederp ...

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SSSD as claimed above, then the nsswitch.conf entries should be as follows for netrgoups "compat glibc mode" to work

*/etc/nsswitch.conf*

```
passwd: compat
passwd_compat: sss
```

and your /etc/password should have the following

```
-@eeederp
```

not

```
-@eeederp:x:::::
```

to disable any user in that netgroup @eeederp to access the server. not sure why access.conf did not work. however this will work.